# Enterprise Library Logging - How can I prevent the "General Information: 0 :" entry?

Tags: enterprise-library

I'm using [EntLib 5.0 Logging Application Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx). I created a `CustomTraceListener` and while testing it I noticed that each time I log with `Logger.Write()` my listener's `Write()` method is called with

> General Information: 0 :

and then the `WriteLine()` method is called with the expected and desired log content that the TextFormatter produced

I can't figure out why I'm getting that first "General Information: 0 :" message.

Anyone know if that is controlled somewhere in the config?

Answer (score 0):

While investigating why the TextFormatter wasn't being used I [read more about custom TraceListener implementations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650498.aspx) and learned that you need to override the TraceData method as well:

`public override void TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, object data)`

Once I implemented that method the "General Information" messages stopped happening AND my TextFormatter with it's custom template string was being used. All is well!